# Google Play Games has crash on logout

Tags: android, google-play-games

Since migrating Google Play Services to 11.6.0, the following error has been popping up in my crash reports :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zzakb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zzakc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zzg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr.signOut(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.zzaii(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbp.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The occurrence of `signOut` in the stack trace seems to tell that the logout process is involved, but I've been unable to find out what exactly is going wrong.
The code for the logout process is currently the following :

```
protected void logout() {
    if (GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null) {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                mGoogleSignInAccount = null;
                setIgnoreConnectionResolution(true);
                onDisconnected();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, or at least how to report it to Google, that would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you you checked the solution in this [github post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/489)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 : yup, updating the play services did nothing, neither did the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Do you call any PGS methods in onDisconnected? If, so, you should call them before mGoogleSignInClient.signOut() call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to migrate to the new GPS and ran into the same issue as yours.

I fixed it by chance when trying to fix another issue.

All I did was remove signOut from my onStop methods (It was good practice to call disconnect on the onStop method with the previous API).

Since signOut actually clears the account previously selected by the user, when called in the onStop method, it creates all kind of other issues (when checking if the user is signed in, or when silentSignIn would always fail, and especially between activites).

So I don't know if you also call signOut on your onStop, and I'm not sure how it caused my app to crash the same way, but if you do, try without it.

The updated sample apps do not include anything in the onStop method (compared to the previous ones who used to call disconnect), so I guess there is nothing to do on that method.

Hope this helps.